# What do I map varchar type to with Cassandra Java driver 4.13.0?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra, cassandra-4.0

as part of the Cassandra driver migration, I need to migrate a codec registration like bellow.

```java
TupleType tupleType =  cluster.getMetadata().newTupleType(
    DataType.timestamp(), DataType.varchar());

cluster.getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry().register(
   new ZonedDateTimeCodec(tupleType));
```

I am not able to find the `varchar` type in `com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.DataTypes`

```
TupleType tupleType = DataTypes.tupleOf(DataTypes.TIMESTAMP, 
   DataTypes.need-varchar-type)
```

Can u pls suggest what can I do for this mapping?.

Comment: Cassandra java driver 4.13.0 codec registration is simplified.
 In my use case tuple<timestamp, text>
 I can register the codec like bellow. 
CqlSession.builder().addTypeCodecs(ExtraTypeCodecs.ZONED_TIMESTAMP_PERSISTED)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varchar` is the same as the `text` data type, so you can use [TEXT DataType](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.0/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/type/DataTypes.html#TEXT)